# Trying to change regular outlets with GFCI in both bathrooms

Tags: gfci

A few months ago, both outlets stopped working at the same time.

I thought one of them would be feeding another one. So I bought two GFCI outlets to replace both of them in case. When I opened the outlet and tried to find which wire is line and which is load, it seemed like neither has power in them in either of the outlets. They both have four cables with white and black wires in them. So two of them should be line and two should be load (at least that is what my understanding is).

Could it be that it is getting load from somewhere else and that is where the problem is?

Comment: There may also be a 3rd GFCI that you haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely the breaker for the bathroom outlets has tripped.  Or possibly become disconnected somehow.

Start with the easiest first.  Inspect the breaker panel.  Most residential breakers do *not* visibly move the breaker handle when they trip.  To reset the breaker, turn it fully off and then back on.